How can I map a non-flat json data structure to a flat class in C# when deserializing?
I am new to C# and .NET. I am wondering if there is a simple way to map a json data structure that is not flat to a single C# class when deserializing using either the built in JSOn deserialization or a library like the Newtonsoft one.
i.e.
JSON
{
    "id: "1234",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "username:":"jdoe",
    "data": {
        "avatarURL": "https://my.avatar.com/path",
        "avatarThumnailURL": "https://my.avatar.com/path?thumb=1",
    }
}

C# Class
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    public string? AvatarThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

}

I found this attribute but seems to be for just changing the name.
JsonPropertyNameAttribute Class

You could always create a custom json converter for the type (available in both flavors of json libs). I don't believe you can map an individual field to some arbitrary path in the source.

You should distinct between how data should look when serialized or how you need it in memory/code to work with. People will talk about domain models in that context. Said that deserialize the json into a class that fits that structure and then when you need it differently for example the way you show map between the classes representing a User in different domains.

you can create a new Model class DTO that matches the JSON and deserialize it, then map it to the Object of the required type
public class UserDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DataDTO Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataDTO
{
   public string? AvatarUrl { get; set; }
   public string? AvatarThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

}

custom mapper would map data fields as below:
user.AvatarUrl  = userDTO.Data.AvatarUrl;
user.AvatarThumbnailUrl = userDTO.Data.AvatarThumbnailUrl ;


Thanks for the suggestions. Both answers look like good options. I ended up going with this one.
I also found that using a dynamic type seemed to work. I could then do this to get the data.
data.GetProperty("avatarUrl").GetString()
I liked your solution better though.

For that you would need to write custom JSON onverter by inheriting from JsonConverter. Below is draft converter you can use as a base to further explore and bulletproof the solution:
public class FlattenJsonConverter : JsonConverter<User>
{
    public override User? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var user = new User();

        var propertyName = string.Empty;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                propertyName = reader.GetString();
                if(propertyName == "data")
                {
                    ReadData(ref reader, ref user);
                }
                continue;
            }

            if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            {
                // Capitalize first letter
                typeof(User).GetProperty(propertyName[0..1].ToUpper() + propertyName[1..])
                    .SetValue(user, reader.GetString());
                continue;
            }
        }

        return user;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, User value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static User ReadData(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, ref User user)
    {
        var propertyName = string.Empty;
        while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                propertyName = reader.GetString();
            } 
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            {
                // Capitalize first letter
                typeof(User).GetProperty(propertyName[0..1].ToUpper() + propertyName[1..])
                    .SetValue(user, reader.GetString());
            }

            reader.Read();
        }

        return user;
    }
}

And then you can use it like below (you posted invalid JSON, but I corrected it):
var rawJson = @"{
    ""id"": ""1234"",
    ""name"": ""John Doe"",
    ""username"":""jdoe"",
    ""data"": {
        ""avatarUrl"": ""https://my.avatar.com/path"",
        ""avatarThumbnailUrl"": ""https://my.avatar.com/path?thumb=1""
    }
}";

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new FlattenJsonConverter());
var user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(rawJson, options);

Console.WriteLine();

Reference:
How to write custom converters for JSON serialization (marshalling) in .NET
